# Make a form-in-a-div appear on top of content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure this has been asked before but my google-fu was not able to find an answer.

I have a page of content and I want it so when a user presses a link or a button a form appears on top of the content.  Once filled out and submitted it would get passed on to the ajax to process it.

I am sure this has been solved before as I've seen it on websites.  Is there a simple way to do this, such as a jquery plugin or another javascript API?

Or would I have to write the form in the div by hand, overlay it with z-index in css and hide it.  And then when it is called have the form appear?

What's the easiest way to solve this?  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a modal popup that fetches the form from the server through an HTTP request.

There are a lot of examples online.  Check out jQuery ThickBox: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Even better, here is a page with over 30 examples to choose from: http://www.dottony.com/30-useful-ajax-lightbox-and-modal-dialog-solutions/

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the FancyBox plugin (originally meant for displaying pictures, but can be used for forms as well).
See this link: http://fancybox.net/blog, in the middle of the page look for "5. Display login form" example.

Answer (score 1):

Try any of the excellent jQuery "lightbox" type plugins which allow for Ajax content.

Just search "jquery lightbox."

Answer (score 1):

You can write some CSS to show your form on the top with absolute positioning. something like:

```
#inputForm {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 100px;
width: 300px;
height: 200ps;
}
```

and then use following markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Click to login <input type="button" id="btnLogin" />
        </div>
        <div id="inputForm" style="display:none;">
            <!-- your form controls -->
            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" />
        </div>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#btnLogin').click(function() {
                     $('#inputForm').show();
                });
                $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
                         $('#inputForm').hide();
                         // collect form data
                         // make your AJAX request
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course, if you don't want use mega/awesome/best-box plug-in ^^

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other guys: you want something like [thick|light|color|fancy|...]-box. So, to mention my favorite solution: http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/#demos

Good thing is, that you can make it behave like an `iframe` and simply pass the url to the form you want to show ..